How do I count and display unique column combinations when using a case statement
I want to get a count of unique column combinations and display the count by the concatenated string of the column values.  I use a case statement on each column to transform the column values into fewer items.  It ends up displaying the proper concatenation string, but the count is based on the values before they were changed with the CASE statements.  In this example I want to count the car brand purchased by state.  Any errors in SQL are from my poor typing ability.  The SQL with the actual values works.  I have tried using a temp table, but could not get it to work.
Expected Result - The count represents the concatenated values from the CASE statements
Toyota in Utah      5
Ford in California  6

Actual Results - The concationated CASE values are displayed, but the rows are the count of the values before the case transform.
Purchase             Total
Toyota in Utah       2    
Toyota in Utah       3
Ford in California   2
Ford in California   4

Column Data
Item            City
86 Corolla      Salt Lake
86 Corolla      Salt Lake
Toyota Corolla  Salt Lake City
Toyota Corolla  Salt Lake City
Toyota Corolla  Salt Lake City
F150            Los Angeles
F150            Los Angeles
Ford Taurus     San Francisco
Ford Taurus     San Francisco
Ford Taurus     San Francisco
Ford Taurus     San Francisco

SQL
select concat(
CASE 
 WHEN Item LIKE ('%Corolla%') THEN 'Toyota'
 WHEN Item LIKE ('%Taco%') THEN 'Toyota'
 WHEN Item LIKE ('F%') THEN 'Ford'
ELSE Item
END,  -- END AS 'Brand' gives me a syntax error
' in ',
CASE
 WHEN City LIKE ("Salt Lake%") THEN 'Utah'
 WHEN City LIKE ("Las%") THEN 'California'
 WHEN City LIKE ("San%") THEN 'California'
ELSE City
END)

AS Purchase, count(*) as Total
FROM PurchaseOrders
GROUP BY Item, City
ORDER BY Purchase


Put your entire expression into the group by. It's grouping on the original column (with the same name) rather than what you intended.

Why do you use LIKE here? This can lead to a very poor performance and I don't get why this should be required. Does your table have further columns? The state should be saved in a separate column and not be determined by the city. This should urgently be fixed. Furthermore, there should be a separate column with the brand (Ford, Toyota). Different items can of course have the same brand. Even if you can't fix this, don't use LIKE, rather use an IN clause like ...IN ('Salt Lake', 'Salt Lake City',...)...

Which dbms are you using?

Your data model is poorly designed. You need to store State for each City. E.g. San Antonio is in Texas and Las Vegas in Nevada. And Firebird is/was a Pontiac.

Why I use LIKE.  The actual data is an IP address.  Each IP address is in one of many different datacenters.  The query is intended to show the communication between data centers, not individual IP addresses (servers).  I use CASE and LIKE to assign the IP addresses to the proper datacenter.  I could replace the LIKE with = and all of the appropriate IP addresses.  I also only look at the past three minutes of data.

As alraidy said in my previous comment, you will be on high risk to produce incorrect results unless you improve your DB structure and add separate columns for the state and the brand and get rid of this LIKE nonsence.

Put the Purchase case expressions etc in a derived table (i.e. a FROM clause subquery). GROUP BY its result:
select Purchase, count(*)
from
(
    select concat(
    CASE 
     WHEN Item LIKE ('%Corolla%') THEN 'Toyota'
     WHEN Item LIKE ('%Taco%') THEN 'Toyota'
     WHEN Item LIKE ('F%') THEN 'Ford'
    ELSE Item
    END,  -- END AS 'Brand' gives me a syntax error
    ' in ',
    CASE
     WHEN City LIKE ("Salt Lake%") THEN 'Utah'
     WHEN City LIKE ("Las%") THEN 'California'
     WHEN City LIKE ("San%") THEN 'California'
    ELSE City
    END) AS Purchase
    FROM PurchaseOrders
) dt
GROUP BY Purchase
ORDER BY Purchase


This worked perfectly.  Great explanation too.

Change
GROUP BY Item, City

To
GROUP BY 1

Which groups by column number 1.
You were grouping by multiple columns that your expression rendered to the same value, but had different value combinations and so were returned as separate rows.

The issue is in the 'group by'.  You should be able to group by the purchase field that you are generating:
select 
    concat(
        CASE 
            WHEN Item LIKE ('%Corolla%') THEN 'Toyota'
            WHEN Item LIKE ('%Taco%') THEN 'Toyota'
            WHEN Item LIKE ('F%') THEN 'Ford'
            ELSE Item
        END,
        ' in ',
        CASE
            WHEN City LIKE ("Salt Lake%") THEN 'Utah'
            WHEN City LIKE ("Las%") THEN 'California'
            WHEN City LIKE ("San%") THEN 'California'
            ELSE City
        end
    )AS Purchase, 
    count(*) as Total
FROM 
    PurchaseOrders
GROUP BY 
    Purchase
ORDER BY 
    Purchase


That's a product specific assumption. In general, and in the ISO/ANSI SQL standard, that is not possible.

I am using SQL Server 2014.  It does not like the Group By Purchase.
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
