Creating a new column to calculate USD prices to EUR
I'm using the S&P Global Delta Share to get all sorts of fuel prices for ships.
The problem is that some of the prices are in USD, and others are in EUR.
I need all the prices in EUR.
Now luckily there is a symbol (EUUSD00) to do this in the dataset. So I have created the following query to create the new column 'VALUE_EURO' (see query below).
The only problem I have now is that for some dates (ASSESSDATE), there is no row with symbol EUUSD00.
So in that case my VALUE_EURO column returns NULL. In these cases I want to use the last available exchange rate before the date that has no exchange rate, so the last available row with symbol EUUSD00 before the missing date, but I cant get that right.
Query:
select
  symbol,
  DESCRIPTION,
  ASSESSDATE,
  MODIFIEDDATETIME,
  bate,
  VALUE,
  CURRENCY,
  CASE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN VALUE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'USD' THEN VALUE / (
      SELECT
        AVG(VALUE)
      FROM
        `sp_marketdata`.`mdv2`.`pricedata`
      WHERE
        symbol = 'EUUSD00'
        AND ASSESSDATE = outerQuery.ASSESSDATE
    )
  END AS VALUE_EURO
from
  `sp_marketdata`.`mdv2`.`pricedata` outerQuery
where
  symbol in (
    'AAYWT00',
    'AAJUS00',
    'AAWGH00',
    'HVNWC00',
    'GTFTM01',
    'ENXEM01',
    'EUUSD00'
  )
  and ASSESSDATE between '2024-05-01'
  and '2024-06-28'
  and BATE in ('c', 'u')
order by
  ASSESSDATE DESC

Example output:
enter image description here
So in this example, the rows that have no VALUE_EURO need to use the EUUSD00 for the previous date (in this case 2024-04-30) to calculate the VALUE_EURO value.

Are you sure you're using SQL Sevrer? You've used back ticks for delimit identifiers, however, T-SQL doesn't use those; it uses brackets ([]) and double quote (").

As for your question, consumable sample data (ideally DDL and DML statement) and expected results will help us help you here. Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Im using the SQL editor in Azure Databricks, should I change the tag?
I have no idea how to get DDL and DML statements, sorry :(

I don't know Azure Databricks, but the tag suggests that uses Apache Spark, not SQL Server.

A quick search for "ddl dml SQL" will clarify

My select statement is in the post, so thats a DML statement right?

Look into other questions and convert your picture into a text table. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78920938/how-do-i-count-and-display-unique-column-combinations-when-using-a-case-statemen or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78925435/flag-all-bosses-in-meeting-based-on-org-tree

You can probably change your code to something like: / (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM sp_marketdata.mdv2.pricedata WHERE symbol = 'EUUSD00'  AND ASSESSDATE <= outerQuery.ASSESSDATE ORDER BY ASSESSDATE DESC)

In the question, we want to see a description of the data structure (DDL), an example of the data and the expected result.
That is DDL
create table testdata (symbol varchar(10),description varchar(100)
  ,assessdate datetime, modifieddatetime datetime, bate varchar(1)
  ,value float,currency varchar(3),value_euro float);

Source data as query (DML)
insert into testdata values
 ('ENXEM01','Endex NL Base EUR/1Mhw 1Mo','2024-05-02 00:00:00'
  ,'2024-05-03 01:33:24','c',65.37,'EUR',65.37)
,('EUUSD00','ECB US$ per Euro','2024-05-02 00:00:00'
  ,'2024-05-02 14:05:45','u',1.0698,'USD',1.0)
,('AAJUS00','ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge','2024-05-02 00:00:00'
  ,'2024-05-01 17:28:09','c',740.5,'USD',692.1854552)
,('AAJUS00','ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge','2024-05-01 00:00:00'
  ,'2024-05-01 17:07:06','c',752,'USD',null)
,('EUUSD00','ECB US$ per Euro','2024-04-30 00:00:00'
  ,'2024-04-30 14:05:43','u',1.0718,'USD',1.0)
;

OR source data as text table



symbol
description
assessdate
modifieddatetime
bate
value
currency
value_euro




ENXEM01
Endex NL Base EUR/1Mhw 1Mo
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-03 01:33:24.000
c
65.37
EUR
65.37


EUUSD00
ECB US$ per Euro
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-02 14:05:45.000
u
1.0698
USD
1


AAJUS00
ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-01 17:28:09.000
c
740.5
USD
692.1854552


AAJUS00
ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge
2024-05-01 00:00:00.000
2024-05-01 17:07:06.000
c
752
USD
null


EUUSD00
ECB US$ per Euro
2024-04-30 00:00:00.000
2024-04-30 14:05:43.000
u
1.0718
USD
1



Test data contains rows

where currency='EUR' - nothing to do
where currency='USD' and value_euro is not null - nothing to do
where currency='USD' and value_euro is null - this is interesting row
currency rate for previous date - we find this row in subquery

Desirable output as text table



symbol
DESCRIPTION
ASSESSDATE
MODIFIEDDATETIME
bate
VALUE
CURRENCY
VALUE_EURO




ENXEM01
Endex NL Base EUR/1Mhw 1Mo
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-03 01:33:24.000
c
65.37
EUR
65.37


EUUSD00
ECB US$ per Euro
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-02 14:05:45.000
u
1.0698
USD
1


AAJUS00
ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge
2024-05-02 00:00:00.000
2024-05-01 17:28:09.000
c
740.5
USD
692.185455225276


AAJUS00
ULSD 10ppmS FOB ARA Barge
2024-05-01 00:00:00.000
2024-05-01 17:07:06.000
c
752
USD
701.623437208434



See query example.

Calculate last preceding date, where we can find EUR/USD rate

(select max(c.ASSESSDATE) from testdata c
           WHERE c.symbol = 'EUUSD00' and c.assessdate<=outerQuery.assessdate)


Take EUR/USD rate for this date

SELECT VALUE
      FROM testdata p
      WHERE p.symbol = 'EUUSD00'
        AND p.ASSESSDATE 
        =(select max(c.ASSESSDATE) from testdata c
           WHERE c.symbol = 'EUUSD00' and c.assessdate<=outerQuery.assessdate)

Full query
select symbol, DESCRIPTION,
  ASSESSDATE, MODIFIEDDATETIME, bate,
  VALUE, CURRENCY,
  CASE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN VALUE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'USD' THEN VALUE / (
      SELECT VALUE
      FROM testdata p
      WHERE p.symbol = 'EUUSD00'
        AND p.ASSESSDATE 
        =(select max(c.ASSESSDATE) from testdata c
           WHERE c.symbol = 'EUUSD00' and c.assessdate<=outerQuery.assessdate)
    )
  END AS VALUE_EURO
from
  testdata outerQuery
where
  symbol in ( 'AAYWT00','AAJUS00','AAWGH00','HVNWC00','GTFTM01','ENXEM01','EUUSD00')
  and ASSESSDATE between '2024-05-01' and '2024-06-28'
  and BATE in ('c', 'u')
order by
  ASSESSDATE DESC

fiddle

The question "get the best or most recent X" is usually accomplished with a SELECT TOP 1 query with appropriate filters and an ORDER BY.  In your case, you can try changing your inner query to:
      SELECT TOP 1
        VALUE
      FROM
        sp_marketdata.mdv2.pricedata
      WHERE
        symbol = 'EUUSD00'
        AND ASSESSDATE <= outerQuery.ASSESSDATE
      ORDER BY
        ASSESSDATE DESC

This assumes that you only want the latest or current value for a given date/time, and not an average of multiple values that occurred on the same day.
Full query:
select
  symbol,
  DESCRIPTION,
  ASSESSDATE,
  MODIFIEDDATETIME,
  bate,
  VALUE,
  CURRENCY,
  CASE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN VALUE
    WHEN CURRENCY = 'USD' THEN VALUE / (
      SELECT TOP 1
        VALUE
      FROM
        sp_marketdata.mdv2.pricedata
      WHERE
        symbol = 'EUUSD00'
        AND ASSESSDATE <= outerQuery.ASSESSDATE
      ORDER BY
        ASSESSDATE DESC
    )
  END AS VALUE_EURO
from
  `sp_marketdata`.`mdv2`.`pricedata` outerQuery
where
  symbol in (
    'AAYWT00',
    'AAJUS00',
    'AAWGH00',
    'HVNWC00',
    'GTFTM01',
    'ENXEM01',
    'EUUSD00'
  )
  and ASSESSDATE between '2024-05-01'
  and '2024-06-28'
  and BATE in ('c', 'u')
order by
  ASSESSDATE DESC

See this db<>fiddle for a demo (using ValNik's test data).
